# How does std::atomic ensure atomicity

Tags: c++, atomic

If I have a code `a = a + 1`, now I understand that there are multiple CPU level operations required to execute this, but how does definining `a` as `std::atomic<int>` make these multiple transactions atomic?

Does it change the way CPU instruction are executed. I'd assume that it will have to shrink the number of instructions to 1 somehow, so that any context switching does not cause unreliable results, but how does it do that?

If the compiler can always create code like that, why not always do that?

Comment: `I'd assume that it will have to shrink the number of instructions to 1 somehow` atomics are not required to be lock-free. There could very well be a mutex in there, however modern cpu's have great support for atomic operations. [Just compile some atomic operation and check the generated assembly.](https://godbolt.org/z/gHpe19)

Comment: Wish people would stop saying "just check the assembly" all the time. Not all of us can make head or tail of it!

Comment: Note that `a = a + 1` won't be made atomic by making `a` use `std::atomic` - you also have to use one of the atomic operations, such as `a++`.

Comment: BTW notice that even making `a` an `std::atomic_int` doesn't make `a = a + 1` atomic (but will work for e.g. `a += 1`). _edit_ too slow :-)

Comment: "If the compiler can always create code like that, why not always do that?" because atomic operations are way more expensive. It's not just a matter of doing the operation in a single instruction - with multiple core machines, extra synchronization to memory and to caches has to be employed.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - squeezed in front by mere seconds :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is an atomic instruction that can be issued (for a known possible atomic operation), then this atomic instruction is issued, otherwise it's going to be with a lock mechanism.

There is a function (C++17) that tells you if the atomic type is always lock-free or not: [`is_always_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free).
Be aware that if this function returns `false`, at least some operations are not lock-free (not necessarily all of them). These non lock-free operations will usually be more expensive than atomic operations (themselves more expensive than traditional operations).

Not all hardware support all combinations of atomic operations, so different compiler backends will generate different solutions, sometimes with a single atomic operation, sometimes with a locking mechanism.

So it cannot always create such 1-instruction code.

Comment: + this is why it does not "always do that", because in the case where a mutex is required, this is far from free, and you rarely need it (in the grand scheme of things)

Comment: I'm addressing the final line of the question (which you didn't do :P)

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You're welcome to steal it and mould it into a part of your answer - that was the purpose of it

Answer (score 3):

> [B]ut how does definining a as std::atomic make these multiple
>   transactions atomic?

It doesn't make the "multiple transactions" atomic in an arbitrary expression (e.g., it won't help in your `a = a + 1` example). Rather, you need to use an operation like `a++` which is guaranteed to be atomic. In that case, how it is implemented depends on the compiler and hardware, but the most common strategies are:

- A single instruction *atomic operation* is used, which can automically increment the value in memory. On x86, this would be [something like](https://godbolt.org/z/yJT7D1) the `lock add` instruction.
- Some type of [compare-and-exchange (CAS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) or [load-linked store-conditional (LL-SC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) loop is used to repeatedly attempt to do the increment in an atomic fashion. You can [see LL-SC in action](https://godbolt.org/z/6NL_CY) on MIPS64.
- Finally, on platforms that don't support such operations, or where the data type is incompatible with those instructions, a lock can obtained to exclude any concurrent access while performing the operation with regular non-atomic instructions. Most mainstream platforms won't need to fall back on this for atomic types, but you can still see [an example here](https://godbolt.org/z/XeaAob) on an old ARM compiler.

You may be able check the behavior on your compiler and hardware combination by examining the generated assembly. Sometimes this is tricky because the compiler may call into a function implemented in a runtime library, in which case you'll have to examine the source or disassembly for that function. This means that the same binary can have different implements for atomic operations on different hosts, if the runtime library implementation differs!

> If the compiler can always create code like that, why not always do
>   that?

The compiler doesn't always generate these because they are expensive at a hardware level. For example, a normal (non-atomic) addition usually takes 1 cycle or less<sup>2</sup> on most modern CPUs<sup>1</sup>, while an atomic addition may take 15 to 100 cycles. Approaches that use CAS or LL-SC are generally even slower and require retry loops, bloating the binary size.

---

<sup>1</sup> Up to perhaps a handful of cycles on some micro-controller class CPUs - but there atomic operations are often less relevant since there may not be multiple cores.

<sup>2</sup> It depends how you measure it - an addition usually takes one cycle to *complete* (latency), but you can often execute more than one independent addition in the same cycle. For example, modern Intel CPUs can execute four in one cycle.